# Unable to place the Pods Evenly

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubectl

No matter how hard I tune this, I am not able to make the Pods spread evenly across the four nodes in AWS EKS Cluster. Here's the Pod yaml.

```
  nodeSelector:
    node_env: my-node-name
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
            - key: node_env
              operator: In
              values:
                - my-node-name
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: app
              operator: In
              values:
              - my-app-name
          topologyKey: topology.kubernetes.io/hostname
    podAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                  - my-app-name
          topologyKey: node_env
  topologySpreadConstraints:
    - maxSkew: 1
      nodeAffinityPolicy: Honor
      topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
      labelSelector:
        matchExpressions:
        - key: app
          operator: In
          values:
          - my-app-name
```

There are seven nodes under the EKS Cluster - four for apps pods, two for envoy pods and one for miscellaneous pods.

I am looking to place four replicas of a pod and evenly distribute it in those apps pods node.

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible to utilize `topologySpreadConstraints` alongside `podAntiAffinity/podAffinity`, I wouldn't recommend doing so. I suggest you review the following answers for a comparison:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73159361/19206466

If your objective is to achieve an even distribution across nodes, you can accomplish this by combining `nodeAffinity` with `topologySpreadConstraints`. Use `nodeAffinity` to select the appropriate nodes, ensuring that your EKS nodes have the `node_env: my-node-name` label attached. To list a node's labels, you can use `kubectl describe node <eks_node>`.

Then, employ `topologySpreadConstraints` to evenly distribute the pods across these nodes; setting `maxSkew: 1` should suffice for evenly distributing the pods across the selected nodes.
In addition, make sure that the `app: my-app-name` label exists in your app pods' template.

**Important Note:**
In case you are utilizing an auto-scaler for your EKS cluster (e.g. Karpenter) you may also need to define the `minDomains` `topologySpreadConstraints` attribute supported since Kubernetes 1.25.
In your case, it would define the minimum amount of required EKS nodes.

For more information, refer to: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/#spread-constraint-definition

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: node_env
            operator: In
            values:
              - my-node-name
topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    nodeAffinityPolicy: Honor
    topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        app: my-app-name
```

**References**

- Karpenter: https://github.com/aws/karpenter/issues/2572